# Unable to write to file using BufferedWriter

Tags: java, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have this Method that Lists the Files in a Directory and I need to write the same to a file. Apparently my

System.out.println();
is able to list the files and their Sizes and the Dates they were Modified. But My bufferedWriter Does not write Anything in the File. Here is My Method;

```
 public void walk( String path, int limit ) throws IOException {

            File root = new File( path );
            File[] list = root.listFiles();
            File rep = new File("report.txt");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
            if (list == null) return;
            long size;
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(rep));
            for ( File f : list ) {
            size = f.length()/1000/1000;
                if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
                    walk( f.getAbsolutePath(), limit );
                }
                else {
                if(size >= limit){
                    System.out.println( "File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() + " " + size  + "MB Last Modified Date: " + sdf.format(f.lastModified()));
                    bw.write("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() + " " + size  + "MB Last Modified Date: " + sdf.format(f.lastModified()) + "\n");

                    }
                }
            }
          bw.close();
        }
```

What Am I Missing? I need to write the Out to the File report.txt but the file is empty.

Comment: try `bw.flush();` after the `for` loop

Comment: This writes Only the Last result... but it is the Closest I have gone so far :)

Comment: Then use a `StringBuffer` and append values to it in the `for` loop and write it when `for` loop exits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you're trying to open multiple buffered writers to the same file when it's calling itself through recursion. Try creating your writer outside of this method and pass it in as a parameter.

---

**Example**

```
public void myCallingMethod() throws IOException{
    File rep = new File("report.txt");
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(rep));
    walk("my/path", 4, bw);
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: But I have initialized the BufferedWriter Outside the recursive for loop :P

Comment: Not really, @Stanley. In the recursion, you open another file. And so on.

Comment: @Stanley But a new BufferedWriter will get initialised to the same file everytime the method is called. Also when it finishes the recursion if the "path" at the root has just one directory, it will not write anything to it and will flush out an empty file. Maybe you should pass the BufferedWriter in the recursive call so that the same writer instance is used by all the recursive calls.

Comment: Can you direct me to an example because I May not be getting you correctly coz what I am trying o do is not Working.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the code which might solve your problem.
I tried the same.

```
public class example {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Directory path here
    String path = "C:\\";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    File folder = new File(path);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    File file = new File("report.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    long size;
    int limit = 2;
    for (File f : listOfFiles) {
        size = f.length() / 1000 / 1000;

        if (size >= limit) {
            System.out.println("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() + " " + size
                    + "MB Last Modified Date: "
                    + sdf.format(f.lastModified()));
            bw.write("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() + " " + size
                    + "MB Last Modified Date: "
                    + sdf.format(f.lastModified()));
        }

    }
    bw.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

try to call the flush method after you called the write methode like:

```
bw.write("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() + " " + size  + "MB Last Modified Date: " + sdf.format(f.lastModified()) + "\n");
bw.flush();
```

The flush method flushes your stream to your file

Comment: Even with FLush it does not write Anything :(   See My Edit

Comment: Then you should check your write method, maybe you should add an offset and a length
[link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(java.lang.String, int, int))

Comment: You also can try to take a PrintWriter instead of a BufferedWriter
`PrintWriter p = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(rep));`
`p.println(string);`

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable like this

```
StringBuilder fileData = new StringBuilder();
```

And replace

```
bw.write("File:" + f.getAbsoluteFile() + " " + size  + "MB Last Modified Date: " + sdf.format(f.lastModified()) + "\n");
bw.flush();
```

With

```
fileData.append("File:").append(f.getAbsoluteFile()).append(" ").append(size)
   .append("MB Last Modified Date: ").append(sdf.format(f.lastModified()))
   .append("\n") ;
```

And after the `for` loop write `fileData`  to file

```
bw.write(fileData.toString());
bw.close();
```

Comment: You could improve this by using a `StringBuilder` instead of a `String`.  Also the call to `flush` is not needed.

Comment: This gain Writes the Last Result Only.

Comment: Thanks @ViktorSeifert modified answer with `StringBuilder`

Answer (score -1):

You need to do a

```
java.io.BufferedWriter#flush()
```

before the close.

Comment: Even with Flush it does not write :(

Comment: Do you have any files larger than 1M in the directory which you are running this? I noticed that `if(size >= limit)` is filtering out all the files when I ran it. Is there any file whose length is greater than 1000000 ?

Comment: The `BufferedWriter` will receive a `flush` when it is closed.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close()